# How to check all checkbox in the related column in GridView which having multiple checkbox columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

[Columns Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OBPv.png)

I have GridView1 with two seperated checkBox columns.

**Here is the Select/Deselect ALL jquery code below:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("[id*=chkHeader]").live("click", function () {
    var chkHeader = $(this);
    var grid = $(this).closest("table");
    $("input[type=checkbox]", grid).each(function () {
        if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
$("[id*=chkChild]").live("click", function () {
    var grid = $(this).closest("table");
    var chkHeader = $("[id*=chkHeader]", grid);
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
        chkHeader.removeAttr("checked");
    } else {
        $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
        if ($("[id*=chkChild]", grid).length == $("[id*=chkChild]:checked", grid).length) {
            chkHeader.attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    }
});
```

When I check any check all checkbox, I check all checkbox in the Gridview1. But I it must check all checkbox in the related column. How can I do this.?

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Appply seperate css class to each column.

Like for all checkbox in column1 'col1', and 'col2' for all checkboxes in column2.

While checking all checkbox in the column verify which header checkbox was clicked and check only those checkboxes who has class related to column.

Comment: It can be solved with the JQ code that I have posted. I just couldn't choose the related  column bucause It is looking for whole columns in GridView1.